# Create and and change h1 tag every four paragraphs (h1 content contains first ten elements of paragraphs)

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom, appendchild

What I need to do is to create `h1` tag every 3 paragraphs, so I have 12 paragraphs, there should be 4 h1 tags, each needs to contain 10 elements from every three paragraphs.

Example:

h1(content would be first ten elements of each paragraphs below it) p p p h1 p p p and so on.

What I have done so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pastraipos">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("pastraipos");
var children = parent.childElementCount;
    console.log(children);
for (var i=0; i<children; i=i+3){
    var h = document.createElement("H1"); 
    var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");     
    h.appendChild(t);
    parent.insertBefore(h, parent.children[i]);    
}
```

so this code, creates 4 h1 elements, appends it to `<div id="pastraipos"></div>`

What is wrong with it, that it just append child every 3 elements?

My result is:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
```

I think I need next loop just to match the correct index where to append, but the problem is when I add to this loop, second loop - it messes up, I'm stuck here so badly, need your help, thanks.

Comment: cant understand what you're trying to do. can you can us the html output of your code and also an html output of what you're trying to achieve. the first paragraph explanation confuses me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here. The first is that the loop stops too soon. The second is that you are miscalculating the position to insert the new elements.

The reason for both problems is the same: you are forgetting that you are updating the DOM live. Each call to `insertBefore` alters the DOM and alters the number of elements within the parent element.

First, the stopping too soon. You are basing the loop length on a cached version of `childElementCount`. This is incorrect. You need to base it on the live version, because the number of elements keeps increasing. After the first `h1` is inserted, you now have 13 elements, then 14, then 15 and so on. If you just  use `childElementCount` in the conditional, this works fine:

```
for (var i = 0; i < parent.childElementCount; i = i + 3) {
```

Now, the next problem is with the same line of code. Look at what the DOM looks like after the first element is inserted:

```
h1
p
p
p
p
...
```

Where do you want to insert the next `h1`? It's *not* after the third element but after the fourth, which is the third `p` element. You actually need to do `i + 4` each time.

Here is a working example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < parent.childElementCount; i = i + 4) {
```

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("pastraipos");

for (var i = 0; i < parent.childElementCount; i = i + 4) {
  var h = document.createElement("H1");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
  h.appendChild(t);
  parent.insertBefore(h, parent.children[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="pastraipos">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>10</p>
  <p>11</p>
  <p>12</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great explanation, which part is now clear, but would You mind explaining, how to get every first 10 elements of each three paragraphs below h1 tag, and that text content add to h1?

Comment: @TautvydasBūda I don't understand what you mean, but I think that's a different question. You should ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

For your amounts, just 2 fixes: `i+=4` and `i<=children` in your for loop.

```
var parent = document.getElementById("pastraipos");
var children = parent.childElementCount;
console.log(children);
for (var i=0; i<=children; i=i+4){
    var h = document.createElement("H1"); 
    var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");     
    h.appendChild(t);
    parent.insertBefore(h, parent.children[i]);    
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wscourge/h2o22wkr/)

Comment: Yes, indeed, thank you so much, would u mind explaining, how to get first 10 elements of each 3 paragraphs below h1 tag, and that info append to h1?

Answer (score 1):

Within your div you can get all the Ps using a selector, then loop over them and insert an h1 after every 3rd paragraph:

```js
function insertHeadings(id) {
  var paras =  document.querySelectorAll('#' + id + ' p');
  for (var h, i=0, iLen=paras.length; i<iLen; i+=3) {
    h = document.createElement('h1');
    h.appendChild(document.createTextNode('heading ' + i/3));
    paras[i].parentNode.insertBefore(h, paras[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 50%;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="d0">
  <p>p1<p>p2<p>p3<p>p4<p>p5<p>p6<p>p7<p>p8<p>p9<p>p10<p>p11<p>p12
</div>
<button onclick="insertHeadings('d0')">Insert headings</button>
```